# Зачем в LINQ нужна лишняя запись?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два одинаковых LINQ-запроса. Непонятно, зачем в первом запросе прописывать `q => q.Courses`, если в новой коллекции внутри `new` `q` все-равно не используется?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = Student.GetAllStudents().SelectMany(
            q => q.Courses, // зачем нужно это?
            (a, b) => new 
            { 
                Name = a.Name + " " + a.LName, 
                Course = b
            });

        var data2 = from a in Student.GetAllStudents()
                    from b in a.Courses
                    select new { Name = a.Name + " " + a.LName, Course = b };

        foreach (var i in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name + " " + i.Course);
        }
    }
```

Коллекция

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Courses { get; set; }
    public static IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student() {Name = "Dima", LName="Kozyr", Gender="M", Courses = new Collection<string> { "Math", "English", "Art" } },
            new Student() {Name = "Kate", LName="Iguna", Gender="F", Courses = new Collection<string> { "Math", "Physics", "Sport" } },
            new Student() {Name = "Mash", LName="Kozyr", Gender="F", Courses = new Collection<string> { "Math", "Computer", "Art" } },
            new Student() {Name = "Anto", LName="Kozyr", Gender="M", Courses = new Collection<string> { "Math", "English", "Art" } },
        };
        return students;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так просто уберите это и поглядите, что будет. Или найдите документацию по этой функции, что вы вызываете, и там почитайте. Или в чем вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 Если закомментить эту строку, то выдаст ошибку, что аргументы типа не могут определяться по использованию. То есть оно говорит только, что аргумент должен быть, а зачем он там, если он не используется - непонятно.

Comment: Ваша коллекция `q` разбивается на элементы и каждый элемент передается в функцию преобразования в качестве параметра `b`. Таким образом вы указываете, какую коллекцию будете разбивать и передавать дальше.